# Why I am seeing my own server IP in access_log

Tags: centos

if I open my domain access log at /var/log/httpd/domain-access_log in CENTOS I can see so many requests coming from the server itself, like

```
0.0.0.0 - - [19/May/2020:21:40:17 -0300] "GET /img/xxx/xxx.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 110088 "-" "-"
0.0.0.0 - - [19/May/2020:21:40:17 -0300] "GET /img/xxx/xxx.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 172643 "-" "-"
```

0.0.0.0 is the actual server IP.

But so many, like 100s

Is it normal?

Comment: How would we know? A distributed website configured to run on 1 machine and acting as a proxy server maybe?

Comment: Do you have links within your site pointing to itself, such as "http://example.com/about" rather than "/about". Not sure if that makes much difference but was just a thought. I'm not certain how http server handles it, canonical links etc.

Comment: very weird! we might have internal links but this wouldn't be the user IP request instead of the server itself?